# Is given async function and .then() is different or not

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, syntax, async-await

Is working of given both syntax is same or different?

```
functionName.then((data) => {console.log(data)})
            .catch((e) => {console.log(e)});
```

AND

```
(async () => {
   let data = (await client.function(input));
   console.log(data);
})().catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: One uses `functionName`, the other uses `client.function(input)`?

Comment: in your 2nd example you could use `try..catch`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `await` works very much like a `then` call, and in this simple example they are equivalent.

Comment: They're not. There is an additional function definition in the first Promise example. While a small difference, it is there. That function will get added to the event loop call stack whereas in the async example, the `await` call is handled at a lower level in the runtime. Additionally, the named function (`functionName`) means that the function has been saved to memory on its own, in the second example an object is used with a method, which is different. Also, the second example wraps everything in an IIFE, which adds yet another layer and difference.

Comment: @jakerella For such a basic question, the answer of course simplifies a lot. Surely two different codes always do different things in detail, yet here they have **the same effects and result**. That's what the OP wanted to know. Regarding `functionName`, I just assumed it was a lapse on the OPs part and he meant to write `client.function(input)` just like in the other example.

Comment: Sure, but this isn't just about the OP's issue, it's also about other people finding this answer. you say they are "absolutely equivalent", but that is absolutely not true. That said, you're right about the basic execution. If you edit your answer to not include "absolutely equivalent" then I think it's ok.

Comment: @jakerella Done. You could've edited it yourself, it's a community wiki answer :-) The "absolutely" came from my thinking that while `await` can be replaced with a `then` here trivially (making them equivalent) it's not always the case (`await` inside control structures).

Comment: Ah, that's fair... I guess I don't like editing other people's work at an early stage. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While the **output** will be the same, these two will operate slightly differently in the JavaScript runtime.

The `then` handler function in the first Promise example does not exist in the `async` example. While a small difference, it is there. That `then` function will get added to the event loop call stack whereas in the async example, the `await` call is handled at a lower level in the runtime.

Additionally, the named function (`functionName`) means that the function has been saved to memory on its own, in the second example an object is used with a method, which is different and means different memory usage. Also, the second example wraps everything in an IIFE (to assert the `async` nature), which adds yet another layer and difference.

Comment: There are many, many more slight differences, but I doubt any of these matter to the OP.